# "Fast strlen" in C using scalar bithacks

Tags: c, strings, bitwise

I've translated an [implementation of strlen in x86 assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210689/strlen-and-strcmp-implementation-in-x86-fasm-assembly/213558#213558) to C and added alignment checking:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NOT_HIGH_MASK 0x080808080
#define HIGH_MASK 0x7f7f7f7f
#define LOW_MASK 0x01010101
#define mul4(x) ((x) << 2)
#define div8(x) ((x) >> 3)

size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *cptr = str;
    uint32_t i, *s;
    size_t ctr = 0;

    /* Satisfy alignment requirements */
    while((uintptr_t)cptr & (sizeof(uint32_t)-1))
    {
        if(!*cptr)
            return cptr - str;
        cptr++;
    }

    s = (uint32_t *)cptr;

    do {
        i = s[ctr];
        /* Mask off high bit */
        i &= HIGH_MASK;
        /* subtract 0x01 from each byte,
           giving a set high bit if it
           was zero */
        i -= LOW_MASK;
        ctr++;
            /* Test for the set high bit
               and if it is found exit */
    } while(!(i &= NOT_HIGH_MASK));

    /* Find the first high bit set and
       create the corresponding byte index */
    i = div8(ffs(i));
    /* Remove the counter increment from the
       loop and multiply it by 4 to find the
       rest of the byte index */
    ctr = mul4(ctr - 1);

    /* Return the combined byte index with 1
       removed so it doesn't include the null
       terminator itself */
    return i + ctr - 1;
}
```

I'm looking for general critique, but I'd also like additional information in these areas:

- Portability. Is this portable? Will it work on all common platforms (x86, arm, etc.) and possibly some uncommon ones?
- Comments. The comments I've put here seem to already document the code well enough, but is there any additional information I could add?
- Hidden Bugs. This definitely works (and has a noticeable improvement in speed), but are there any hidden bugs relating to alignment requirements or otherwise (such as extended ASCII)? For context, this is part of a standard C/POSIX library implementation.

I might note that I'm relying on my header to use the builtin version of `ffs`. This may be an issue on non-GNU compilers.

If a GCC-compatible compiler (gcc, clang, icc, etc.) is detected during the build process, the flags `-std=gnu99 -O2` are appended to the build flags.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't `cptr - str` appear in the calculations after the main loop as well?

Comment: @harold Oh, of course. That explains the issue I was having. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bug**

`strlen("\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80")` does not return the expected 7.  The `do` loop does not distinguish between `'\0'` and `'\x80'`.

`strlen("\x80\x80\x80")` returns 0, 1, 2  or 3 depending on alignment.

These render  the function broken.

**Why `int32_t`?**

Certainly `int32_t*` marches down the sting at a 4x clip rather than a plodding `char *`.  Yet for a 16-bit `int` machine, `int32_t*` may be slower.  For a 64-bit machine, `int64_t*` could even be faster.   I'd expect a `unsigned *` to work fast or even fastest.  I guess that is why `strlen()` is a library function - each implementation is expected to use its own optimal approach.

**Minor: Clearly use unsigned mask constants**

With bit masking, shifts and subtraction, using unsigned math has less review concerns.

`0x01010101` --> `0x01010101u`.

**Portability**

`while(... & (sizeof(uint32_t)-1))` is a reasonable alignment test but not a *specified* correct one.  Conversion of a pointer to an integer need not follow the usual linear expectations.  I do not know of any implementation where this will not work, but it is not C specified.

Notes:
`uint32_t` is an optional type.  A [unicorn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485) platform may not have it defined.
`uintptr_t` is also an *optional* type.

Could use something like

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef UINTPTR_MAX
  #error "You are kidding me? An implementation without uintptr_t!" 
#endif
```

**Comment nit**

`Mask off high bit` should be "Mask off high bits" or "Mask off each byte high bit", ...

```
/* Mask off high bit */
i &= HIGH_MASK;
```

Comment: I used `&`, not `&&`. The cast to `uintptr_t` was intentional.

Comment: @JL2210 I see the single `&`. (Amended answer as part of the answer did act like `&&` - that part was in error)  The cast to `uintptr_t` does not yield a _specified_ value in which bit-wise adding with  `(sizeof(uint32_t)-1))` results is a specified alignment test.  AFAIK, this is no _specified_ alignment test.

Comment: That's a really opaque way to do alignment; I don't like the assumption that `sizeof (uint32_t)` must be a power of two.  One can imagine an (admittedly not "common") implementation with `CHAR_BIT == 12`, and `sizeof (uint32_t) == 3`.  C++ has `std::align()`; it might be worth creating a similar function here.

Comment: @TobySpeight  `CHAR_BIT == 12, sizeof (uint32_t) == 3` is not possible:  `uint32_t` cannot have padding.  `sizeof (uint32_t)` must be a power of two.  With `CHAR_BIT == 12`, The _optional_ type `uint32_t` cannot be defined.  Yet the larger issue is that an aligned  pointer, when converted to an integer, is not _specified_ to a value with lower bits of 0.  That is just common implementation.  Exotic example per OP's "possibly some uncommon ones?": the least significant bit of the `(uintptr_t)cptr` could be the parity of the address - not useful for determining alignment.

Comment: I feared this when I wrote the code. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @JL2210 Perhaps form a helper function/macro to assess alignment.  I'd expect your initial approach to be fine for 99+% of systems.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For some reason, the results differ between `char s[]="It works!"; strlen(s);` and `char *s="It works!"; strlen(s);`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @JL2210 Different aliments.   Print their pointer values.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, figured it out. I forgot to add `cptr-str` in at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write this kind of code in standard C. It will have to be library-level code compiled with non-standard extensions.

Notably,  `s = (uint32_t *)cptr;` is a strict aliasing violation. It invokes undefined behavior and may cause strange, subtle bugs during optimization etc. In order to get this to work reliably, you have to use non-standard options such as `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.

When dereferencing the pointed-at string as `uint32_t` you must also ensure that the 32-bit access doesn't go out of bounds of the allocated array.

Pedantically, you should cast the result of `ffs` to `uint32_t`, because it returns an `int` type which is signed and you don't want to bit shift signed numbers, even though it will always be positive in this specific case. I'd probably rewrite the macros more type-safe, along the lines of this:

```
#define mul4_32(x) ((uint32_t)(x) << 2)
```

Or, if C11 is an option:

```
#define mul4(x) _Generic((x), uint32_t: (x) << 2)
```

In either case it shouldn't affect performance.

Also please note that `ffs` and `strings.h` are POSIX but not standard C.

Comment: I could've sworn that I said "For context, this is part of a standard C library implementation."

Comment: @JL2210 Yeah but you never mention compiler options, so I have to assume standard C.

Comment: I've added a small clarification to the question. It doesn't seem as if strict aliasing affects this at all...

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the zero detection trick would also detect any 0x80 bytes (€ in CP1252, various different characters in UTF-8 contain 0x80 as continuation byte, for example Hiragana mu: む = "\xE3\x82\x80") as if they were zero-terminators. There are slightly more expensive "contains zero byte" checks that avoid this, for example (sprinkle with parenteses as desired):

```
i = i - LOW_MASK & ~i & NOT_HIGH_MASK;
```

That replaces 3 operations from the original, so it's not *that* costly, and additionally it could be used as fallback test after the simpler test thinks it has found a zero (though that is not favourable for strings with many 0x80 in them). It's not a straight upgrade, so it's for you to weigh the trade-off.

This uses the definition `#define NOT_HIGH_MASK 0x80808080` as used in this question, not `HIGH_MASK = 0x80808080` as may be expected.

This trick operates on the same basic principle as the trick in the question: subtracting 1 from 0 sets the high bit of that byte, because it can borrow all the way through, but any set bit would stop the borrow from reaching the top. However, it fixes the problem of "what if the top bit was already set" by ANDing with `~i` afterwards, rather than by ANDing with `HIGH_MASK = 0x7f7f7f7f` beforehand (which also turns 0x80 into zero).

Comment: That solution doesn't work. Now it gives 7 for a string like `"\x80It works!"`.

Comment: @JL2210 it correctly detects zeroes.

Comment: Mine correctly detects zeroes too.

Comment: @JL2210 OK then let me restate that: it correctly detects zeroes and *only* zeroes.

Comment: `i - LOW_MASK & ~i & NOT_HIGH_MASK` appears to evaluate as `((i - LOW_MASK) & (~i)) & NOT_HIGH_MASK`.  Is that your intent?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, the [original](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) had parentheses around the subtraction but they are redundant.

Comment: That `0x080808080` was a typo. I've corrected it to `0x80808080` in my local copy.

Comment: ...along with that I mixed up `NOT_HIGH_MASK` with `HIGH_MASK`. I've fixed that too, thank you.